# trying to format hex into little endian in c

Tags: c, hex, endianness

So I'm trying to get the sum of the values in a buffer, however, the values need to be rearranged in order to do so. Essentially how do I get C to convert the values in this array:`uint16_t inp[] = {0xFF,0x81,0xFD,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x08,0x00,0x00};` to look like this array: `uint16_t buff[] = {0x81FF,0x00FD,0x0000,0x0800,0x0000}`

Comment: Maybe you should use a loop?

Comment: `buff[0] = ((inp[1] & 0xff) << 8) | (inp[0] && 0xff)`. Generalise and put into a loop.

Comment: Are you sure the original form is big-endian?

Comment: Do you want the array formatted differently if the platform itself is big-endian vs little-endian?  That is, are just trying to flip the bytes consistently regardless of platform?  Or are you trying to flip the bytes to match the platform?

Comment: @kaylum thank you! i did a bit of a variation but you gave me what I needed to understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @kaylum, I figured it out:

```
 #include <stdio.h> 
 #include <stdint.h>
 
uint16_t inp[] = {0xFF,0x81,0xFD,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x08,0x00,0x00};
uint16_t buff[sizeof(inp)/2];


int main(){
    int sum = 0;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(buff);i=i+2){
        buff[i] = ((inp[i+1] | 0x00) << 8) | (inp[i] | 0x00);
        //printf("%.4X\n",buff[i]);
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(buff);i++){
        sum = sum += buff[i];
    }
    printf("%u\n",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sum = sum += buff[i];` - what's that? I guess you wanted either `sum += buff[i];` or `sum = sum + buff[i];`

Comment: `| 0x00` is redundant. It says "if original bit is 0 make it 0, if the original bit is 1 make it 1". That is, it does nothing and removing it will not change the result at all.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(buff);i++){` <<-- sizeof(buff) is too large.